# how to create subtitles spacing when entering jwplayer

Tags: css, jwplayer, subtitle

I'm having trouble with subtitles when I put the backgroudopacity, the background line is inserted on the top line, is there any way to fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KZ4X.png)
Và đây là mã javasript của tôi:

```
  var playerInstance = jwplayer('WatchPlayer');
        clientSide.player = playerInstance;
        
        playerInstance.setup({
            sources: <?= $source_video ?>,
            captions: {
                color: '#FFF',
                fontSize: 16,
                backgroundOpacity: 40,
                edgeStyle: 'raised'
            },
            allowfullscreen: true,
            width: '100%',
            aspectratio: '16:9',
            playbackRateControls: true,
            autostart: true,
            mute: false,
            cast: {},
```

Hope everybody help please

I have tried and failed, hope someone here can help me

Comment: Not sure about jwplayer styling. If it is compatible with regular CSS, you can try `lineHeight` or another font.

Comment: seems regular css doesn't work with jwplayer :(

Comment: Found the doc at https://docs.jwplayer.com/players/reference/setcaptions_styles_ . Not many styling options. Could you try another fontFamily?